# Fix total price without tax in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce

I'm facing an issue with my custom plugin with woocommerce what remove tax from Total price when a User click on a checkbox.
I'm using Wordpress 6.2, PHP 7.4, Woocommerce, Woocommerce checkout manager, woocommerce subscriptions and Memberships.
In my case:
When a user click on the check box the price of total recurring changes but the total remains the same as with tax.
I'm calculating the total with these lines of code inside my plugin:

```
`public function customize_cart_total($total, $cart) {

        $totals[] = $total;

        $customer_country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();  
        if( "IT" === $customer_country ) {
            // Get the custom field value from the WooCommerce session
            $retrive_data = WC()->session->get( 'custom_field_value' );

            // If custom field value is available and truthy, use the cart's subtotal excluding taxes
            if ( $retrive_data ) {
                $total = $cart->subtotal_ex_tax;                
            }
        } else {
            // For all other countries, use the regular cart total
            $total = $totals[0];
        }

        return $total;
    }`
```

I'm expecting to have my total price as Total recurring, instead of 286 Euro It must be 275.
[ORDER EXAMPLE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TobuS.png)

Comment: And how you get $cart ? Also you should use woocommerce_before_calculate_totals and there do your modifications. Also check if user is logged in then run this code just to optimize it.